# How can I disable the iPhones's AutoFill bar on my <input>s?

Tags: iphone, html, webkit, cordova, autofill

I've got a PhoneGap app with an `<input type="number" />`.
The problem is that the keyboard has a toolbar above it with Previous, Next, and Autofill.

There's only one form field, so Next and Previous aren't useful. The number will be different each time and isn't contact info, so AutoFill also isn't useful.

Is there a way to hide or disable this toolbar?

[image]

Comment: If the whole toolbar would be disabled, how would the user be able to hide the keyboard? The "Done" button would be gone as well wouldn't it?

Comment: @mobweb You can tap outside of where the keyboard is to hide it. There's plenty of space for that.

Comment: OK yes you could do that. But that might not work in all cases. So I'm thinking that Apple wouldn't allow this toolbar to be hidden because the user always expects to be able to close the keyboard that way. :/

Comment: Turns out I was wrong? It seems that there is a way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718411/how-do-i-install-this-script-into-phonegap-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

iOS looks at form elements Names, ID's or Classes, along with labels that correspond with these inputs. Try changing the names of these to more obscure titles to stop AutoFill, it's worked in my experience.