# How do I install this script into PhoneGap for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, cordova

I don't know any Objective-C, that is why I'm using PhoneGap to create an iOS app. There is a big flaw in PhoneGap for iOS. The keyboard constantly has the form assistant (the 'next', 'previous' and 'done' buttons.) There is very little information on the web on how to get rid of this, all of the Stackoverflow questions about it said it was practically impossible. But after a while I stumbled upon this tutorial. The bottom paragraph tells you how to do it. And it works, I downloaded and tested the finished app.

But since I have no idea how to do almost anything in Xcode, or in Objective-C, I have no idea what files the two sections of code go into, he doesn't say in the tutorial.

Can anyone tell me where in the PhoneGap apps files it goes? I'd appreciate it massively, this has been bugging me all day.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

And this

```
RichTextEditorViewController *viewController = [[RichTextEditorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RichTextEditorViewController" bundle:nil];
self.viewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
```

Also this

```
- (void)removeBar {
    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Locate UIWebFormView.
    for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {       
        // iOS 5 sticks the UIWebFormView inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIPeripheralHostView"].location != NSNotFound) {
            for (UIView *subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView in [possibleFormView subviews]) {
                if ([[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIWebFormAccessory"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Word of advice. Learn obj-c and you will be much happier.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have come across the need to do this myself.  I am an IOS developer, but needed to use phonegap to keep costs down for multiplatform dev.

Anyway, i fixed your code. As, i guess, you dont want to spend your time learning obj-c, you just need to replace the contents of your MainViewController.m with the following:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) removeBar {
    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Locate UIWebFormView.
    for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {       
        // iOS 5 sticks the UIWebFormView inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIPeripheralHostView"].location != NSNotFound) {
            for (UIView *subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView in [possibleFormView subviews]) {
                if ([[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIWebFormAccessory"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*) notification {
    // remove the bar in the next runloop (not actually created at this point)
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

@end
```

As a word of warning, this is a bit of a hacky solution (but then so is using phonegap!), and may break in future versions of iOS.  But i guess we fix that when it comes to it...

Comment: Dude, thanks ALOT!

I'm surprised your answer didn't come up through my previous googlings.

This answer definitely deserves way more upvotes.

Comment: After trying this I ran into a little problem. Although this does remove the black bar from display, the bar is sort of "still there", it affects how the webview scrolls. Meaning, if some input field is "behind" that bar, then the system will force the view to scroll up

Comment: it may be possible to resize the window i.e. keyboardWindow.frame = CGRectMake(a,b,c,d)  You will then need to resize any subviews in a similar manner...this is not a problem for me, so not tried it.

Comment: if someone else looking for that solution @hasenj has asked for, here's the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10796550/207616

Comment: For some reason I have this thin black line still hovering above my keyboard: http://imgur.com/rbi33. Any ideas on how to remove it?

Comment: I know the solution is almost 3 years old but couldn't run this on iOS 8. Keyboard's not showing at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number PhoneGap plugins to enhance control of the keyboard. Although I haven't used this  yet it looks like the Ionic Keyboard Plugin may provide what you're trying to do.

"Hide the keyboard accessory bar with the next, previous and done buttons."
Method: cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar

To add it:
cordova plugin add https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git