# Phonegap: completely removing the black bar from the iPhone keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova, soft-keyboard

We're using Phonegap to develop our mobile app, and we borrowed code from here to remove the black next/prev/done bar from the keyboard:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276023/35364

What that code does is it finds the black bar, as a UIView object, and calls 'removeFromSuperview' on it.

We're not familiar with the iOS SDK/API. So while we can look at the code and get an idea of what it's doing, we can't tell if it's doing it properly, or how to improve it.

The specific problem we're running into:

We have a text field for writing a message, and we're manually controlling the placement of this field to be exactly above the keyboard, similar to the native sms app. In other words, we're putting it where the black bar was supposed to be.

When we focus/type in the message field, the system pushes the view up. It seems like this is a mechanism to make sure the text field is not invisible when the user types in it.

This is happening even though the text field *is* visible.

I noticed that by putting the input field right above where the black bar would normally be (as oppose to behind it), the view doesn't scroll.

So it seems the system somehow thinks the black bar is still there!

(To double check: when the black bar is not removed, and we put the text field right above it, we can focus and type in it, and the view would not scroll).

So the question is:

Why does the "system" push the content up when editing a text-field that's place right "behind" where the black bar is supposed to be? Is it because the black bar is not completely removed yet? Do we need to do something to "completely" remove the black bar? Do we need to force iOS to recalculate the size of the keyboard? or what exactly?

Is this mechanism (pushing up the view) implemented by iOS's UIWebView, or by Phonegap?

Is there any phonegap app that has solved this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replace

```
[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
```

with

```
UIScrollView *webScroll = [webView.subviews lastObject];
CGRect newFrame = webScroll.frame;

float accesssoryHeight = subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView.frame.size.height;
newFrame.size.height += accesssoryHeight;

[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
[webScroll setFrame:newFrame];
```

it resize the content scroll view for the amount of missing accessory space. It is as far using "private API" as the other code. In detail it isn't using private API directly but if Apple decide to change how a view appears (in this case Keyboard and WebView) then it will crash.
For example if they rename `UIWebFormAccessory`, your code will not work anymore.

EDIT:
on iOS 5.0+ you can call `webView.scrollView` directly. So you can split the code to have a pre iOS 5 fallback:

```
UIScrollView *webScroll;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0) {
    webScroll = webView.scrollView;
} else {
    webScroll = [webView.subviews lastObject]; // iOS 2.x (?) - 4.x
    // make sure this code runs appropriate on older SDKs
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like it might work. One thing though I'm not sure what 'webb' is supposed to be. I tried `UIScrollView *webScroll = [self.webView.subviews lastObject];` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: ups yeah it was my temporary webView, an `IBOutlet`. But it should work like you tried. Please `NSLog(%@, self.webView.subviews)`. Maybe you have more subviews, I only had one (the scrollView)

Comment: `.scrollView` is only available in iOS 5.0+; you asked for a solution which will work on 4.0 too ;) … but you can implement a switch if you like `if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0)`. But make sure the code for 4.0 works as expected

Comment: @relikd on ios5 it works perfectly. But on ios6 there is a thin black line across the top of where the black bar would have been. any ideas on how to get rid of this too?

Comment: Yes @rlay3 this happens to me as well, have you be chance stumbled upon a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://github.com/don/KeyboardToolbarRemover

You will have to know though, there is no Cordova.plist file as of Phonegap 2.3.0 - instead edit your config XML file with the following:

```
<plugin name="KeyboardToolbarRemover" value="KeyboardToolbarRemover" />
```

in the  branch