# iPhone Keyboard manipulation on Phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

iam currently developing an app fi iPhone with Phonegap 1.6.1 and Sencha Touch 2.

I want to create an Plugin which edit my Keyboard for one Page, cause i want to make an comment and i don't need the status bar, alo it looks not good.

I found already a solution to hide this bar, but only for all the time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276023/35364

at this link, the bar will be removed.

Iam not really familiar with Objective C, i know it would be better to know more about it, but i not got the time to learn it.

So my Question is, how to put the code from abodes link, to a Phonegap Plugin to show and hide the bar.
Some background color changes would be very nice to.

The Problem from the code above is, that the first opening from the keyboard don't will have the affects without the status bar, when i tried by my self to putt this in my Plugin.

Something like removeStatusBar and addStatusBar.

I Also get an Problem with pushing up the view when the keyboard appears. is there a way to view the keyboard without pushing anything?

I found a link, but this didn't helps.

[Phonegap: completely removing the black bar from the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746998)

It could be a Sencha Touch Problem, cause when i tap an the screen, the view will push down like i want ...