# Remove form assistant from uiwebview only on specific html files (Phonegap)

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, cordova, uiwebview

As most of us phonegap users already know by now, **there's a way to remove the form assistant** (prev, next, done) bar from uiwebview. It has been asked several times on stackoverflow, here are some examples:

[How do I install this script into PhoneGap for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718411/how-do-i-install-this-script-into-phonegap-for-ios)

[Phonegap: completely removing the black bar from the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746998/phonegap-completely-removing-the-black-bar-from-the-iphone-keyboard/10796550#10796550)

[Remove form assistant from keyboard in iPhone standalone web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904892/remove-form-assistant-from-keyboard-in-iphone-standalone-web-app)

This applies to all textfields in all files of one's phonegap app. 
What has not been discussed, however, is **whether this somewhat hacky solution can be applied to one or several textfields only, or on specific html-pages** inside one's phonegap application.

Since **phonegap users can't target html textfields with "native" C code**, I assume the first simply can't be done (I would love to be proven wrong here though.) But perhaps, it might be possible to **remove the form assistant bar from specific html documents** by using the above mentioned solutions and targeting specific html files. If so, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution that does this sort of perfectly. The only problem is that when the keyboard deploys, the canvas jumps a little as a consequence of the bar being remove. This is how's it's done:

### Download [this](https://github.com/don/KeyboardToolbarRemover) plugin from GitHub

### HTML

Include the Javascript after cordova.js and before your application's javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="keyboard_toolbar_remover.js"></script>
```

In your Javascript, include the module

```
var toolbar = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/keyboard_toolbar_remover');
```

To disable the toolbar

```
toolbar.hide()
```

To re-enable the toolbar

```
toolbar.show()
```

### Installation

Copy `KeyboardToolbarRemover.h` and `KeyboardToolbarRemover.m` to the Plugins directory of your iOS project.

Copy `keyboard_toolbar_remover.js` to the `www` directory of your project.

Edit `Cordova.plist`. Add an entry under the plugin section mapping **KeyboardToolbarRemover** to **KeyboardToolbarRemover** as shown below:

[image: Add plugin entry]