# IOS prev/next button close keyboard unexpectedly

Tags: ios, cordova, input, keyboard

I'm currently using PhoneGap (Cordova) to build an App on iPad/iPhone.

One of my page in the app (in html/css/js), have more than 100 input type Number.
When i use finger to target each of them, it's working like a charm.
But when i use the prev/next button from IOS Keyboard, sometime, i don't know why, keyboard slide to down and when i try to open it again with targeting a input with my finger keyboard just blink... Impossible to fixe it without a scroll to release all event.

I've clean my code, refactored some part, look on google and stackoverflow if someone had the same problem but i found nothing...

Did someone know if it's a UIWebView problem ? Or phoneGap? or something else?

Thank's for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to just remove the next/previous buttons from your app entirely, the new Phonegap/Cordova 2.6.0rc1 has made this incredibly simple.

In your **config.xml** file, just set the `HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar` preference to `true`.

Comment: thank's. I think i will do it for my app. Prev/next just make application dance when we spam it. it's funny to see but not really for the client..

Answer (score 0):

In order for those two buttons to work you need to specify their behavior and it seems that it is not specified. Made some research and I think you have two options. Either you get rid of the next/previous buttons at all like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746998/phonegap-completely-removing-the-black-bar-from-the-iphone-keyboard/10796550#10796550) or you override textFieldShouldReturn: in a way similar to what is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1351090/1845303) post.

Comment: Hey thank's for your answear. My problem is not an IOS Problem (in my opignon) but i will try the two link. Thank's